# Toggle in list items should not respond to click outside the toggle element

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am using material-ui in my react project.I want toggle to work only when toggle element is clicked and not any other part of list item.How do I achieve this?

```
<List>
  <Subheader>Priority Interruptions</Subheader>
  <ListItem primaryText="Events and reminders" rightToggle={<Toggle />} />
  <ListItem primaryText="Calls" rightToggle={<Toggle />} />
  <ListItem primaryText="Messages" />
</List>
```

Answer (score 0):

create a state key called `toggleComponent` and set it with the toggle element on click. and if `this.state.toggleComponent === toogleElementID` show the toggle.

with this only element will be toggle at one time